# How to create a blockchain for record keeping using Ethereum Parity/ IPFS?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ipfs

Currently trying to create a private blockchain application used for record keeping and its been suggested to me to use Ethereum parity and IPFS. However, as a final year student, I have not had any experience with blockchain technologies.

I've taken the time to learn the fundamental concepts of blockchain, so I do understand enough to begin development.

I was wondering whether there are any useful resources that could be suggested to build knowledge in these two technolgies, or any tutorials to perform the task at hand?

Also if there are any better ways to create this, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Ethereum is public blockchain but you can make it private by running your owns nodes and creating your own private network. But if you want to make the transactions private in the network then ethereum will not be suitable option for that because all the transactions are a public in the network and any one can see the content of the transactions. The better option would be hyper ledger as there some are ways in that to make the transactions private and give access or permission to selected nodes who can view transactions. And its a private blockchain.